# windows command prompt is showing errror

Tags: path, command, command-prompt, powershell-3.0

"C:\Users\Varsha\OneDrive\Desktop\git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."
this is what it appers when ever i try to copy the path of a folder or a file into the command promt.

Comment: what are you trying to do in command prompt that might help you get a more definite answer. my best guess is the quote at the end. this could work for you: C:\Users\Varsha\OneDrive\Desktop\git

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].